# How to get the value of crossed item from the multiple select in select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the select2 plugin version 3.5.2. I am using the multiple select. Now suppose I selected a value from the dropdown list and then removed it again by clicking on the cross icon, how can I know its value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 provides [different](http://select2.github.io/select2/#events) events that you can use to catch selection, removal or other events. For your case you can use `select2-removed` event,

```
 $("#multipleSelectExample").on("select2-removed", function(e) {
     alert(e.val);
    })
```

Here is an working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/180/).

Also, I suggest you to use latest version of Select2 if possible as they have added tons of new features that you can work on with.